# Ejabberd 14.12 mod_mam multisession issue

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have configured ejabberd 14.12 server with enabled multisession and working mod_mam (XEP-0313 v0.2, https://github.com/kongo2002/ejabberd-mod-mam, http://xmpp.org/extensions/attic/xep-0313-0.2.html)

mod_mam works great when i send message from user with one connected session to different user with one session

However if user-1@example has 2 online sessions with different resources and user-2@example sends to user-1@example (to bare JID) one message - mod_mam saves two messages

ejabberd log:

```
<0.708.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:http_put:792 Looking for session: <<"2a16b709927907352b5696d8c7fbb4bdc641c736">>
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_sync_event:440 New request: {http_put,152025,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"152025">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"2a16b709927907352b5696d8c7fbb4bdc641c736">>},{<<"key">>,<<"e9815d19f02d2ca9249209cdd82c818fae01b821">>}],[{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}],251,1,<<>>,{{10,0,2,2},49075}}
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_http_put_event:575 New request: {http_put,152025,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"152025">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"2a16b709927907352b5696d8c7fbb4bdc641c736">>},{<<"key">>,<<"e9815d19f02d2ca9249209cdd82c818fae01b821">>}],[{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}],251,1,<<>>,{{10,0,2,2},49075}}
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:rid_allow:866 Previous rid / New rid: 152024/152025
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:608 Actually processing request: {http_put,152025,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"152025">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"2a16b709927907352b5696d8c7fbb4bdc641c736">>},{<<"key">>,<<"e9815d19f02d2ca9249209cdd82c818fae01b821">>}],[{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}],251,1,<<>>,{{10,0,2,2},49075}}
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:619 Key/OldKey/NextKey: e9815d19f02d2ca9249209cdd82c818fae01b821/4b0850aed0c7d411c41f28c041f0e176db7cf4d7/4b0850aed0c7d411c41f28c041f0e176db7cf4d7
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:659  -- SaveKey: e9815d19f02d2ca9249209cdd82c818fae01b821
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:671 reqlist: [{hbr,152025,<<"4b0850aed0c7d411c41f28c041f0e176db7cf4d7">>,[]},{hbr,152024,<<"882220e875a29152d9b15510b8673137e8360e42">>,[]}]
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:717 really sending now: [{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}]
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:322 route
    from {jid,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ch_jsjac">>,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ch_jsjac">>}
    to {jid,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}
<0.496.0>@mod_mam:handle_cast:313 Packet: {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_local:do_route:296 local route
    from {jid,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ch_jsjac">>,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ch_jsjac">>}
    to {jid,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user"...>>},{<<"type">>,<<...>>}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...}]}
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:514 session manager
    from {jid,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ch_jsjac">>,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ch_jsjac">>}
    to {jid,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user"...>>},{<<"type">>,<<...>>}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...}]}
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_sm:route_message:658 sending to process <0.586.0>
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_sm:route_message:658 sending to process <0.649.0>
<0.615.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:prepare_response:914 OutPacket: [{xmlstreamelement,{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ch_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}}]
<0.615.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:send_outpacket:1056  --- outgoing data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message xmlns='jabber:client' from='user-2@example/ch_jsjac' to='user-1@example' type='chat'><body>2-222</body></message></body>
 --- END --- 
<0.580.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:prepare_response:914 OutPacket: [{xmlstreamelement,{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ch_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}}]
<0.580.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:send_outpacket:1056  --- outgoing data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message xmlns='jabber:client' from='user-2@example/ch_jsjac' to='user-1@example' type='chat'><body>2-222</body></message></body>
 --- END --- 
<0.496.0>@mod_mam:handle_cast:313 Packet: {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ch_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}
<0.496.0>@mod_mam:handle_cast:313 Packet: {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ch_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2-222">>}]}]}
```

We can see double 'handle_cast' from mod_mam.

When i querying messages from archive i got something like this:

```
<message xmlns='jabber:client' from='user-1@example' to='user-1@example/42114606331421936688301010'>
    <result xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp' id='54C104E31E374104E800009B'>
        <forwarded xmlns='urn:xmpp:forward:0'>
            <delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' stamp='2015-01-22T14:10:43Z'/>
            <message from='user-2@example/8658298161421935653320719' to='user-1@example' type='chat'>
                <body>
                    2-222
                </body>
            </message>
        </forwarded>
    </result>
</message>
<message xmlns='jabber:client' from='user-1@example' to='user-1@example/42114606331421936688301010'>
    <result xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp' id='54C104E31E374104E800009C'>
        <forwarded xmlns='urn:xmpp:forward:0'>
        <delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' stamp='2015-01-22T14:10:43Z'/>
            <message from='user-2@example/8658298161421935653320719' to='user-1@example' type='chat'>
                <body>
                    2-222
                </body>
            </message>
        </forwarded>
    </result>
</message>
```

But i want receive only one message without duplicate.

Similarly if user-1@example has 3 online sessions with different resources and user-2@example sends to user-1@example (to bare JID) one message - mod_mam saves two messages.

ejabberd log:

```
<0.690.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:http_put:792 Looking for session: <<"2a16b709927907352b5696d8c7fbb4bdc641c736">>
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_sync_event:440 New request: {http_put,151909,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"151909">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"2a16b709927907352b5696d8c7fbb4bdc641c736">>},{<<"key">>,<<"97451cccc5e5f52563e625169fbc6fecc17ae950">>}],[{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}],251,1,<<>>,{{10,0,2,2},47540}}
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_http_put_event:575 New request: {http_put,151909,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"151909">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"2a16b709927907352b5696d8c7fbb4bdc641c736">>},{<<"key">>,<<"97451cccc5e5f52563e625169fbc6fecc17ae950">>}],[{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}],251,1,<<>>,{{10,0,2,2},47540}}
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:rid_allow:866 Previous rid / New rid: 151908/151909
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:608 Actually processing request: {http_put,151909,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">>},{<<"rid">>,<<"151909">>},{<<"sid">>,<<"2a16b709927907352b5696d8c7fbb4bdc641c736">>},{<<"key">>,<<"97451cccc5e5f52563e625169fbc6fecc17ae950">>}],[{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}],251,1,<<>>,{{10,0,2,2},47540}}
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:619 Key/OldKey/NextKey: 97451cccc5e5f52563e625169fbc6fecc17ae950/17ba9df4939c3fbd9c7f5021af54e4edb6d11496/17ba9df4939c3fbd9c7f5021af54e4edb6d11496
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:659  -- SaveKey: 97451cccc5e5f52563e625169fbc6fecc17ae950
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:671 reqlist: [{hbr,151909,<<"17ba9df4939c3fbd9c7f5021af54e4edb6d11496">>,[]},{hbr,151908,<<"7a3ebe3b5639ddcc6f73e004c58966e21364257d">>,[]}]
<0.606.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:process_http_put:717 really sending now: [{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}]
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:322 route
    from {jid,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ex_jsjac">>,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ex_jsjac">>}
    to {jid,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}
<0.496.0>@mod_mam:handle_cast:313 Packet: {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_local:do_route:296 local route
    from {jid,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ex_jsjac">>,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ex_jsjac">>}
    to {jid,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user"...>>},{<<"type">>,<<...>>}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...}]}
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:514 session manager
    from {jid,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ex_jsjac">>,<<"user-2">>,<<"ch">>,<<"ex_jsjac">>}
    to {jid,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>,<<"user-1">>,<<"ch">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user"...>>},{<<"type">>,<<...>>}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...}]}
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_sm:route_message:658 sending to process <0.586.0>
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_sm:route_message:658 sending to process <0.649.0>
<0.607.0>@ejabberd_sm:route_message:658 sending to process <0.683.0>
<0.615.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:prepare_response:914 OutPacket: [{xmlstreamelement,{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ex_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}}]
<0.615.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:send_outpacket:1056  --- outgoing data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message xmlns='jabber:client' from='user-2@example/ex_jsjac' to='user-1@example' type='chat'><body>3-333</body></message></body>
 --- END --- 
<0.580.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:prepare_response:914 OutPacket: [{xmlstreamelement,{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ex_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}}]
<0.580.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:send_outpacket:1056  --- outgoing data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message xmlns='jabber:client' from='user-2@example/ex_jsjac' to='user-1@example' type='chat'><body>3-333</body></message></body>
 --- END --- 
<0.686.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:prepare_response:914 OutPacket: [{xmlstreamelement,{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ex_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}}]
<0.686.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:send_outpacket:1056  --- outgoing data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message xmlns='jabber:client' from='user-2@example/ex_jsjac' to='user-1@example' type='chat'><body>3-333</body></message></body>
 --- END --- 
<0.496.0>@mod_mam:handle_cast:313 Packet: {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ex_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}
<0.496.0>@mod_mam:handle_cast:313 Packet: {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ex_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}
<0.496.0>@mod_mam:handle_cast:313 Packet: {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user-2@example/ex_jsjac">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user-1@example">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"3-333">>}]}]}
<0.580.0>@ejabberd_http:process_header:283 (#Port<0.5639>) http query: 'POST' /http-bind/
<0.580.0>@ejabberd_http:process_request:448 client data: <<"<body rid='568139' sid='fd0a27af99432dc8b6a252ce6dc87e35da715cc1' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='f4967d3d77af57b2c35847986de0720b8ad6215c' > </body>">>
<0.580.0>@ejabberd_http:process:359 [<<"http-bind">>] matches [<<"http-bind">>]
<0.580.0>@ejabberd_http:process:363 [{'Accept-Language',<<"ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4">>},{'Accept-Encoding',<<"gzip, deflate">>},{'Referer',<<"http://localhost:3000/profile">>},{'Accept',<<"*/*">>},{'Content-Type',<<"text/xml; charset=UTF-8">>},{'User-Agent',<<"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36">>},{<<"Origin">>,<<"http://localhost:3000">>},{'Content-Length',<<"166">>},{'Connection',<<"keep-alive">>},{'Host',<<"localhost:5280">>}]
<0.580.0>@mod_http_bind:process:68 Incoming data: <body rid='568139' sid='fd0a27af99432dc8b6a252ce6dc87e35da715cc1' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='f4967d3d77af57b2c35847986de0720b8ad6215c' > </body>
<0.580.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:parse_request:1128 --- incoming data --- 
<body rid='568139' sid='fd0a27af99432dc8b6a252ce6dc87e35da715cc1' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' key='f4967d3d77af57b2c35847986de0720b8ad6215c' > </body>
```

Questions:

1. It is normal behaviour for mod_mam(XEP-0313) or bug of module?
2. How i may fix it?

Issue on github: https://github.com/kongo2002/ejabberd-mod-mam/issues/7

Comment: I think this question should be addressed directly to the ejabberd developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_mam from [ejabberd-contrib](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_mam) works perfect. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

From the XMPP MAM specification, it looks like you need to query on full JID (with the resource) if you do not want to get message from all resources. It seems like the correct behavior.

Reference: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#filter-jid

Comment: Yes if i send messages to each of available resources by full JID it seems correct.
But i send only one message to bare JID and router sends it to each of resources.
I think more correctly save one message before routing.

Comment: That's not what the MAM specifications says, in my understanding. The MAM module need to store the message as received by each resource. This is to be able to recreate full history for each resource.